# Django Chroniker: How to stop a custom command when it is running

Tags: python, django, cron, celery

I am currently testing Django chroniker for long-running task.

Yes I also tested Celery for a (long) time, but I want to give it a try with django-chroniker anyway because it integrates more out of the box admin stuff to start & stop.

The problem I am facing is that while "run" does work, the stop button in django only displays a nice message but does not seem to actually stop my process.

So I created a very simple custom command:

```
import time
import logging
import logging.config

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

from longrunningfunction import run_extraction

class Command(BaseCommand):
  help = 'Closes the specified poll for voting'
  logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')

  def handle(self, *args, **options):
    logger = logging.getLogger('top')
    logger.debug('Launching test_cmd %s %s', args, options)
    run_extraction()
```

So now that the command is launched, I click on stop in the admin. 
So, what do I need to do so that this is taken into account in my code? How can I interrupt the execution of run_extraction?

I also saw in the source code that the job "force_stop" field is set to True. So that I would need to pass a reference to that field and check it regularly?

--EDIT 28/08/2015
After exposing the problem on IRC, I am now considering the 3 following solutions:

1. Using signals for run_extraction to detect the change of state and act accordingly. 
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/
2. Using postgres notify triggers http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-notify.html
3. Set a chron to run every minute, get all objects with force_start or force_stop to True then act accordingly.

Note: 2 & 3 are Y3K ideas on django irc channel.

Best!

Answer (score 2):

> Well, it sounds like you really want reactivity here. PGSQL has some "NOTIFY" feature IIRC? Maybe take a look on that.
>
> Hmmm or if you don't mind, set a chron to run every N minutes and get the X objects with either force_start or force_stop True and then call what you need. Don't know how performance-wise is this option.

From #django on IRC :)